# Windows Live Messenger connection via Javascript

Tags: javascript, xmpp, windows-live-messenger, messenger

I have given up on solving this one on my own, and any help would be greatly appreciated.
My final goal is to implement WLM (windows live messenger) into my company's website. For the purpose I can use javascript and / or php, but I personally greatly prefer Javascript since I think it would be easier for me to debug any future errors, since I can observe the traffic.

What I fail to do is connect to the WLM XMPP service, after I have obtained all the needed info. In the documentation the only help provided at this point sounds something like "Consult your xmpp library for info on how to connect to the service". I have tried conncting using Strophe, however I do not really know if I am actually able to, since I read WLM does NOT support BOSH service  ( http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/messengerconnect/thread/fb7af36c-aa77-4c9b-b8ab-8206427469be)? After reading that I was also left a bit clueless as to how the entire process of receiving messages is accomplished. Also in my understanding javascript would NOT let me send any http requests to another domain, which is what I am actually trying to do (from what I understand) when communicating to the XMPP service.

Although I think I understand the rest of the process - authentication, connection etc., I failed to find a way to get past the authentication point via javascript. Any suggestions / code examples would be greatly, greatly appriciated...

This ( http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/messengerconnect/thread/5f0d6428-5664-4c97-8d36-87dd17d3d7fa) is a forum thread in the MSN connect forums, where I have asked a few questions and gotten a few replies, in case any1 needs further info.

Have a great day all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLM run no BOSH service. This means to be able to connect to WLM from Java Script with Strophe you must run your own BOSH connection manager for this. A good BOSH CM for this case is Punjab ( https://github.com/twonds/punjab ).

Comment: So your words are the translation of the meaning "The XMPP implementation provided by Windows Live Messenger does not support BOSH or non-SSL communications", as seen in their forums (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/messengerconnect/thread/fb7af36c-aa77-4c9b-b8ab-8206427469be), and not the way I understand it - WLM NOT supporting BOSH AT ALL...?

Comment: no, you didn't really understand what BOSH exactly is. XMPP normally works with TCP/IP sockets. An alternative connection method is BOSH which is based on comet style HTTP. Not every server software has build in BOSH and even when a server software supports it many public servers have disabled it. In this case you can install and maintain your own BOSH server (eg. Punjab) which acts like a proxy. It accepts BOSH connections and opens a "regular" XMPP session over sockets to WLM.

Comment: So the BOSH server would have 2 connections, 1 that does not close at all - to the WLM XMPP server - and one to the user (that gets re-opened in some long interval, what I understand as 'Long pooling'). If there are many users, there would exist many open sockets from the BOSH server to the WLM  XMPP server. If this is the case, nothing should prevent me to open a socket to my server, and server side to transfer anything to the other open connection... (thus using entirely sockets,and no BOSH?) Feel free to correct any of these statements, or do say if I understand things right. Thanks alot:)

Comment: ya I think you got it. From Java Script you can talk only HTTP. So from Java Script you talk HTTP to your connection manager (PunJab), which forwards it on the open socket to WLM over TCP.